# passing variable to partial loop

Tags: zend-framework

Could it be possible to pass the values in partial loop. for code

EDIT:: in my file where partial is called, i've another array to pass. and i want S/N for array

```
 <?php echo $this->partialLoop("partials/destination.phtml", $this->deslist);?>
```

and i my partial/destination.phtml file i have

```
<td><?php echo ++$count; ?></td>
```

i am getting warning message

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: count in 
    /var/www/globaltours.com/application/modules/admin/views/scripts/partials/destination.phtml 
    on line 2 1
```

i wanted to display the count(order) of the items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View variables are in `$this`; use `$this->count` to access the `count` variable:

```
<td><?php echo ++$this->$count; ?></td>
```

Assuming you have passed the variable to the view like this:

```
$view->partialLoop('view-script.phtml', array(
    // loop 1
    array(
        'count' => 0,
        'other_variable' => 'value',
        'other_variable' => 'value',
    ),
    // loop n
    array(
        'count' => 0,
        'other_variable' => 'value',
        'other_variable' => 'value',
    ),
));
```

Comment: @user576875 i've got other variables to pass

Comment: my array loads from the database, so still i would have problem, +1 for idea

Answer (score 0):

You miss something like:

```
$count = 0;
```

Comment: dont know where to do it. if i do it in my file from where partial is called then i won't go to to partial.phtml file when i do it in partilal.file then i wont work out